# Multiple Key events handling

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, keyevent

I'm trying to make a game (Ping Pong) in Java. At this moment, I'm still stuck at moving the rackets independently.

To summarize the game, I have 2 objects that are controled by the same keyboard. Racket_1 should go up with "a" pressed, and go down with "q" pressed, and Racket_2 should do the same with "p" and "m". When I try to move the rackets randomly, it seems to me that keyPressed and keyReleased dont get triggered in some cases (some order of pressing and releasing keys).

This is my sample code (I simulated movements with printing the keys pressed):

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PingPong extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private boolean isAPressed;
    private boolean isQPressed;
    private boolean isPPressed;
    private boolean isMPressed;

    public PingPong() {
        this.setSize(400, 100);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        char key = e.getKeyChar();
        switch (key) {
            case 'a':
                isAPressed = true;
                break;
            case 'q':
                isQPressed = true;
                break;
            case 'p':
                isPPressed = true;
                break;
            case 'm':
                isMPressed = true;
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("a is " + isAPressed + ", q is " + isQPressed
        + ", p is " + isPPressed + ", m is " + isMPressed);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        char key = e.getKeyChar();
        switch (key) {
            case 'a':
                isAPressed = false;
                break;
            case 'q':
                isQPressed = false;
                break;
            case 'p':
                isPPressed = false;
                break;
            case 'm':
                isMPressed = false;
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("a is " + isAPressed + ", q is " + isQPressed
        + ", p is " + isPPressed + ", m is " + isMPressed);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PingPong().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If multiThreading is required please, try to make it simple, because I'm a novice.

Comment: If you've searched this site for similar type questions, you'll often see the Swing mavens recommend not to use KeyListeners but to instead use Key Bindings, and I agree with them for many reasons. I suggest you do just that, search for similar questions, as you'll likely find answers that will help you.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to respond late, but I was away from any kinda internet connexion.

I've tried all links given by the commenters, but they didn't help me. However, I was half way with Threads, cuz I knew that if two tasks can execute at the same time, then my problem would be solved. So I tried to create two players: 1st moves with "a" & "p" and the 1nd with "p" & "m", and I implemented the run method in my Panel where I act depending on the key pressed or released, and my problem was solved.

I thank everybody for their help to me.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause is you've fallen foul of the focus requirements of `KeyListener`.

`KeyListener` will only trigger key events if the component it is registered to is focusable AND has focus.  This is a well known issue with `KeyListener`.

Instead you should try using the key bindings API, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details.

Comment: I will definitely do it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for an example. The `KeyboardAnimation.java` example will allow you to use bindings on separate components.